# Interfaces for Rich Domain Models

Tags: unit-testing, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

Should Rich Domain Models have interfaces to assist with isolation during unit testing (e.g. when testing a service that uses the model)?

Or should the Rich Domain Model behaviour be involved in any related unit tests?

*Edit:*

By Rich Domain Model I'm specifically referring to domain entities that contain logic (i.e. non-anaemic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, the Domain Model is the part that you should keep isolated from everything else. The Domain Model may *use* interfaces so that it's isolated from external systems, etc.

However, in the most common scenarios, the Domain Model is what you're trying to protect from the deteriorating influences of external systems, UI logic, etc. - not the other way around.

Thus, there's little reason to put interfaces on the Domain Model.

Comment: I understand your points, I'm more referring to app or domain services for example which may be orchestrating a number of domain model objects. Should those objects behaviour be mocked away in order to test the service logic only?

Comment: @BrettPostin How are those Services distinct from the Domain Model? Don't they describe the *behaviour* of the Domain Model?

Comment: Apologies I should probably be more specific, I really mean rich domain entities. Should their logic be mocked when unit testing other classes that make use of them?

Comment: @MarkSeemann How do you write isolated/solitary tests (in the sense of J.B. Rainsberger's 'integrated tests are a scam' argument or Jay Fields' 'working effictively with unit tests', i.e. faking out almost all collaborators) for your domain objects? If you want to go down that road you need seams in place. In C# for example you can't just provide a fake collaborator class without "virtual"izing all the things or having an interface in place. I know this might be taking isolated testing a bit too far, but I've always wondered about this issue. Thoughts?

Comment: @prgmtc You can use Test Doubles for Domain behaviour when they are what [DDD](http://amzn.to/WBCwx7) calls *Services*, but it's difficult to do with *Entities*. OTOH, in my experience, I've never seen a real, *rich* (non-anemic) Domain Model anyway, so that tends to not be a problem in practice. I don't say that they don't exist; but I also believe that they are rarer than most people think.

Comment: @prgmtc I was in the same boat a while ago, until I realized that inside a domain model, the system under test ("star" in Rainsberger terminology) is the whole Aggregate rather than just one object. An Aggregate doesn't talk to anything but itself and most of the meaningful logic lies in the invariants happening at its entry point, at the aggregate root level. Trying to test each of its entities in isolation would be like trying to test an object's private methods separately.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely involve domain model behaviour in your unit tests. There's absolutely no point in mocking this part. You should really only be mocking external systems.

Answer (score 2):

> Should Rich Domain Models have interfaces

I'd say no, because

- Domain behavior happens inside a **well-delimited bubble**. A given command triggers changes in a single aggregate. Conceptually, you don't have to isolate it since it basically just talks to itself. It might also issue messages (events) to the outside world, but testing that doesn't require the domain entities themselves to be mockable.
- Concretely, domain entity (or value object) behavior is **fluid** -- it happens all in memory and is not supposed to directly call lower level, I/O bound operations. There will be no performance impact to not mocking stuff in your tests as long as the system under test is a small prepared cluster of objects (the Aggregate and maybe the thing calling it).
- Domain model is a realm of **concrete** concepts. Ubiquitous language terms reflected in your entity or value object class/method names are usually prosaic and unequivocal. There's not much need for abstraction and polymorphism there -- which is what interfaces or abstract classes are for. The domain is less about generic contracts or interfaces providing services, and more about real world tasks that take place in the problem domain.