# Interfaces / Virtual for Domain Models for Unit Testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, interface, moq

I am working on a .Net Core Web Application which is being Unit Tested with NUnit and Moq. Example below is very simplified for question purposes.

I have a "purchaseOrderService" class that fetches a purchase order from the Repository and calls

```
purchaseOrder.Cancel();
```

before saving to the repository. The PurchaseOrder and StockItem classes are below,

```
public class PurchaseOrder
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<StockItem> StockItems { get; set; }

    public PurchaseOrderStatus Status { get; private set; }

    public void Cancel()
    {
        Status = PurchaseOrderStatus.Cancelled;
        foreach(var stockItem in StockItems)
            stockItem.Cancel();
    }
}

public class StockItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public StockItemStatus Status { get; private set; }

    public void Cancel()
    {
        Status = StockItemStatus.Cancelled;
    }
}
```

In the unit test for my purchaseOrder.Cancel method, i wanted to Mock the stockItem, so I could verify that the cancel cancel method was called once for every stockItem inside the purchase order.

I would typically achieve this with something like.

```
Mock<StockItem> mockSI = new Mock<StockItem>();
mockSI.Setup(x => x.Cancel());
mockSI.Setup( x=> x.Cancel(), Times.Once);
```

However, the domain model isn't exposed as an interface and the Cancel method is not virtual so the Cancel method cannot be overridden for the purposes of a Mock.

This leaves me with 3 options

1. Make the cancel method Virtual - This seems like a terrible idea and exposes it to being overridden at unwanted times.
2. Make an interface for the domain model needing to be mocked - This seems excessive as i would be making the interface for testing only without plan to have any other class inherit the interface and on classes I have full control over. Multiple posts on StackOverflow say that interfaces for Domain Models without good reason is bad practice.

for example,
[Interfaces for Rich Domain Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253606/interfaces-for-rich-domain-models)

3. Treat this as more of an integration test and test the 2 classes working together

At the moment I'm leaning towards making the StockItem class implement an interface. What would you recommend?

Comment: No need to implement interfaces here. Just need to rethink how you verify the expected behavior. check the status of the items after calling cancel and that should be enough to indicate that Cancel was called.

Comment: Thats what i was implying with option 3. But what i found was that i had a unit test testing the cancel method in StockItem and an almost duplicate test in PurchaseOrder. It felt a little wrong, like i was doing something bigger than a unit test

Comment: The go with option 3 as that is the more logical choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to implement interfaces here.

Just need to rethink how to verify the expected behavior.

Check the status of the items after cancelling purchase order and that should be enough to indicate/verify that `StockItem.Cancel` was called.

```
[Test]
public void StockItem_Should_Cancel_When_PurchaseOrder_Cancelled() {
    //Arrange
    var item = new StockItem();
    var purchaseOrder = new PurchaseOrder() {
        StockItems = new List<StockItem> { 
            item
        }
    };

    //Act
    purchaseOrder.Cancel();

    //Assert
    item.Status.Should().Be(StockItemStatus.Cancelled);
}
```